# Groovy assert with contains failing even though I can see the item in the list

Tags: groovy

Groovy assert with contains:

```
assert testList.contains(4)
   |        |
   |        false
   [1, 2, 6, 3, 4]
```

Am I going crazy?

This is the test code:

```
    List testList = tester.getFactors(12)
    assert testList.size() == 5
    assert testList.contains(1)
    assert testList.contains(2)
    assert testList.contains(3)
    assert testList.contains(4)
    assert testList.contains(6)
```

If I remove everything except the contains(4) and contains(6) it fails for either or both of them.

This is the getFactors method:

```
 List getFactors(int number)
     {
      def retList = new ArrayList();
      (1..Math.sqrt(number)).each() { i ->
       if(number % i == 0)
       {
           //add both the number and the division result
            retList.add(i) 
            if(i>1)
                retList.add(number / i)
       }
    }
    retList;
}
```

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do:

```
println getFactors( 12 )*.class.name
```

You can see:

```
[java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.math.BigDecimal, java.lang.Integer, java.math.BigDecimal]
```

So the `6` and the `4` are `BigDecimal` instances, not `Integer` instances

So the `contains` fails (as you are looking for `Integer(6)` not `BigDecimal(6)`

If you change:

```
            retList.add(number / i)
```

to:

```
            retList.add(number.intdiv( i ) )
```

Then your results will stay as Integers, and your asserts should work :-)

BTW, just for fun, your function can be rewritten as:

```
List getFactors( int number ) {
    (1..Math.sqrt(number)).findAll { i -> number % i == 0 }
                          .collectMany { i ->
                              if( i > 1 ) {
                                  [ i, number.intdiv( i ) ]
                              }
                              else {
                                  [ i ]
                              }
                          }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for the rewrite of the function - interesting :)

Comment: @FOOM No worries :-)  I'd even argue the `collectMany` should be: `collectMany { i -> [ i, number.intdiv( i ) ] }`, as if you're going to have `1` as a factor, you may as well have the number itself too :-)  Have fun, and good luck!